# Long running query with huge resultset using java programming

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am looking for technical solution for one of our project requirement but could not get right approach in google.

Below are the requirements.

1) We have long running Oracle query, which runs approximately 1.5 hours on business hours and it returns ~10Million records.

2) We have to insert/ dump this resultset into Sqlserver Db Table using Java programming.

Here are my worries on this requirement. 
It might give (Out of memory) error when retrieving all records using Sql Query. 
It might lead to Network timeout, etc

Planing to do with Spring batch/ kafka stream processor etc, not sure whether its achievable.
Please suggest the java Best approaches/ Technologies to achive this with out any issues. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why java? Databases have bulk data utilities for this kind of thing, that will take a fraction of the time.

Comment: +1 to @NathanHughes—there are numerous DB-DB transfer methods; introducing Java here seems redundant. Can you elaborate on why you want to use Java, in case there's a requirement here not yet articulated?